# How can I implement a like button in Flash?

Tags: facebook, flash, facebook-like

How can I implement a `like` button in Flash?  The official documentation only supports/describes a Javascript solution.

Answer (score 6):

The new Like button isn't possible in Flash (we tried).  However, a solution is possible with Facebook Connect.  Check out our write up on how to do it and why the new button isn't possible.

http://labs.byhook.com/2010/08/03/facebook-like-button-in-flash/